# Grouped bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart, but the bars overlap.

This is the code that I am using:

```r
library(ggplot2)   
 
ggplot(data = opstaR, aes(x = Indicator, y = Percentage, fill = factor(tip))) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_grey(labels = c("Case load change", "Compliance change")) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(-0.15, 0.05),breaks = seq(-0.15, 0.05, 0.05)) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

This is the output:

[image: bar plot]

How can I make the bars not stack to each other?

And how to invert the black/gray pattern?

**Data**

```r
opstaR <- structure(list(Indicator = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L), .Label = c("HbA1c measurment among diabetic patients", 
"LDL-cholesterol measurement among diabetic patients", "Diet advice among diabetic patients", 
"Blood preasure measurment among diabetic patients", "Foot examination among diabetic patients", 
"Blood preasure among hypertensive patients", "Total cholesterol among hypertensive patients", 
"Blood glucose among hypertensive patients", "Lifestyle advice among hypertensive patients", 
"ECG among hypertensive patients", "Lifestyle advice among patients with MI", 
"Blood preasure measurment among patients with MI", "Total cholesterol among patients with MI", 
"LDL-cholesterol measurement among patients with MI", "HDL-cholesterol measurement among patients with MI", 
"Triglycerides measurement among patients with MI", "Blood glucose among patients with MI", 
"ECG among patients with MI"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
    Percentage = c(-0.119461152, -0.119461152, -0.119461152, 
    -0.119461152, -0.119461152, -0.125256348, -0.125256348, -0.125256348, 
    -0.125256348, -0.125256348, -0.139557636, -0.139557636, -0.139557636, 
    -0.139557636, -0.139557636, -0.139557636, -0.139557636, -0.139557636, 
    -0.016017788, -0.01085703, 0.030175594, -0.02377841, -0.011164678, 
    -0.020884472, -0.014592098, -0.013684149, 0.033509796, -0.009671902, 
    0.037509542, -0.018565706, -0.01177768, -0.007261598, -0.005188794, 
    -0.008428487, -0.010241197, 0.002690945), tip = c("Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_compliance_rate", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_compliance_rate", "Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_compliance_rate", "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_compliance_rate", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_compliance_rate", "Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_compliance_rate", "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_compliance_rate", 
    "Change_in_case_load", "Change_in_compliance_rate", "Change_in_case_load", 
    "Change_in_compliance_rate", "Change_in_case_load")), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Andrea, thank you. How did you put data. I could not find that option.

Comment: If you run `dput(opstaR)` you will get the output starting with `structure(list(c(`. It's helpful because it's quicker to load into R compared to downloading a text file and importing it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small tweak, remove the `position = "dodge"`. For the colors, one option is to assign it yourself.

```
opstaR %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Indicator, y = Percentage, fill = factor(tip))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Case load change", "Compliance change"),values = c("grey","black")) +  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(-0.15, 0.05),breaks = seq(-0.15, 0.05, 0.05)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Anurag, thanks. However, I prefer that each bar stats from 0, depening % value.  Those bars represent population change and event change. For instance is it not clear what the second pair represents.  So, it is better to see every bar in the pair with one above another, as it can be seen in the excel.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear in how you want the bar chart to look?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. https://media.springernature.com/lw685/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1186%2Fs13584-022-00516-x/MediaObjects/13584_2022_516_Fig2_HTML.png I hope you can see this picture. Interestingly, I made plots as I wanted but less number of pars. Perhaps, the reason is the large number of groups.

Comment: By the way have you noticed that some of your indicator data have two percentages for the same "tip" value? Try ```library(tidyverse)
opstaR %>% 
  dplyr::filter(str_detect(Indicator,"ECG among patients with MI"))```

Comment: It is going to impossible to reproduce the kind of graph you have linked if all the values in "Indicator" do not have two values, one each for - Change_in_case_load  and Change_in_compliance_rate

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I made some plot using this code and similar dataset. https://ibb.co/jRRZQCg